# Tengo una System.Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException en List<Object> obj = new List<Object>(); C#

Tags: c#

En mi proyecto si lo compilo en entorno de debug/local, funciona perfecto. Pero en el
entorno de producción tengo este error:

> System.Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. at WebLogistica.Controllers.HomeController.VerEntrega(String identi) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\DesarrolloWebLogistica\WebLogistica\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 94 at WebLogistica.Controllers.HomeController.VerEntrega(String identi) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\DesarrolloWebLogistica\WebLogistica\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 134 at WebLogistica.Controllers.HomeController.LeerOpcion(String seleccion, String identi) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\DesarrolloWebLogistica\WebLogistica\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 74

Entiendo que `IndexOutOfRangeException` ocurre porque quiero acceder, por ejemplo, a `Array[5]` pero `Array` solo tiene 3 posiciones.

En estas líneas tiene prácticamente las mismas líneas de código que tiene otro método.

Por ejemplo.

El método `LeerOpcion(string seleccion, string identi){}` recibe una opción de una `lista desplegable` e identi es el `valor`

```
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult LeerOpcion(string seleccion, string identi)
            {
                try
                {
                    identi = CleanString(identi);
    
                    if (identi == null || identi == "")
                    {
                        return View("Index");
                    }
    
                    switch (seleccion)
                    {
                        case "pedido":
                            return View("Pedido", VerPedido(identi));
                        case "remito":
                            return View("Pedido", VerRemito(identi));
                        case "entrega":
                            return View("Pedido", VerEntrega(identi)); // Line 74
                    }
    
                    return View();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.error = ex;
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }
```

Este Método `VerEntrega(string identi{}` tiene el problema (comentaré las líneas que se mencionan en el mensaje de error:

```
private List<PedidoViewModel> VerEntrega(string identi)
            {
                string[] imagenes, rutaSplit, imagenRecuperada, rutaImagen, carpetaDia, carpetaMes, carpetaAnio;
                PedidoViewModel pedido;
                List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;
    
                try
                {
                    listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>(); //Line 94
    
                    // \imgAndroid\..   
                    carpetaAnio = Directory.GetDirectories(@"wwwroot\imgAndroid\");
    
                    foreach(var carAnio in carpetaAnio)
                    {
                        carpetaMes = Directory.GetDirectories(carAnio);
                        foreach (var carMes in carpetaMes)
                        {
                            carpetaDia = Directory.GetDirectories(carMes);
                            foreach (var carDia in carpetaDia)
                            {
                                imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(carDia);
                                foreach (var img in imagenes)
                                {
                                    rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
                                    rutaImagen = img.Split("wwwroot");
                                    imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[5].Split("_");
    
                                    if (identi == imagenRecuperada[1])
                                    {
                                        pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                                        pedido.setNumeroPedido(imagenRecuperada[0]);
                                        pedido.setNumeroEntrega(identi);
                                        pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
                                        pedido.setimagenes(rutaImagen[1]);
                                        pedido.setMonto("$11111");
                                        pedido.setCodigoImagen(imagenRecuperada[3]);
                                        listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    return listaPedidos;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.ToString()); // Line 134
                }
            }
```

Y este método es `VerPedido(string identi){}` que es prácticamente exactamente el mismo código que se muestra arriba. Solo cambia las posiciones `.Split()`.

```
private List<PedidoViewModel> VerPedido(string identi)
            {
                string[] imagenes, rutaSplit, imagenRecuperada, rutaImagen, carpetaDia, carpetaMes, carpetaAnio;
                PedidoViewModel pedido;
                List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;
    
                try
                {
                    listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
    
                    // \imgAndroid\..   
                    carpetaAnio = Directory.GetDirectories(@"wwwroot\imgAndroid\");
    
                    foreach(var carAnio in carpetaAnio)
                    {
                        carpetaMes = Directory.GetDirectories(carAnio);
                        foreach (var carMes in carpetaMes)
                        {
                            carpetaDia = Directory.GetDirectories(carMes);
                            foreach (var carDia in carpetaDia)
                            {
                                imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(carDia);
                                foreach (var img in imagenes)
                                {
                                    rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
                                    rutaImagen = img.Split("wwwroot");
                                    imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[5].Split("_");
    
                                    if (identi == imagenRecuperada[0])
                                    {
                                        pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                                        pedido.setNumeroPedido(identi);
                                        pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                                        pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
                                        pedido.setimagenes(rutaImagen[1]);
                                        pedido.setMonto("$11111");
                                        listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    return listaPedidos;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Esta es la ruta que se usa cuando se depura/local:

```
C:\Users\USER\source\repos\DesarrolloWebLogistica\WebLogistica\wwwroot\imgAndroid\2022\09\01\[images]
```

Esta es la ruta que se utiliza para el entorno de producción:

```
\\rivadavia\z$\Virtual\projectName\wwwroot\imgAndroid\2022\08\09\[images]
```

Lo que intento hacer es recuperar el nombre de la imagen (por ejemplo, 911111_12345678_1234-12345678_1_5ca90bcc573b4c29b0082f8dae86f68e.jpg) y usar `.Split("_")` para dividirlos y establecerlos en sus respectivos setters, así que para  `List<Object>` se configurará así:

```
pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
    pedido.setNumeroPedido(identi); // identi es ele valor recibido por parametro, en este caso es "911111"
    pedido.setNumeroEntrega("12345678");
    pedido.setNumeroRemito("1234-12345678");
    pedido.setimagenes("imgAndroid\2022\09\01\911111_12345678_1234-12345678_1_5ca90bcc573b4c29b0082f8dae86f68e.jpg");
    pedido.setMonto("$11111");
    listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
```

Entonces, si envío "NumeroPedido" (primera opción) funciona perfectamente. Si envío "NumeroEntrega" (Segunda Opción) o "NumeroRemito" (Tercera Opción)

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: No crees otro usuario para copiar tu pregunta ;) en su lugar, actualiza la pregunta que ya tenemos con la informacion que te pidieron (yo te aclare donde tenias los problemas, pero a mi no me contestaste nada).

Comment: Cree otra porque perdi las credenciales :c No me acuerdo el mail por lo que no puedo recuperar la contraseña

Comment: entonces trabajemos sobre eso.. asi recuperas tu cuenta...